# doPost not recognise disabled text input field

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have a text input field. When i disable it (disabled) it will not be in the e.paramter list.
When i remove Disableld, the field name is in the e.param.list.

How can i keep my input field disabled and exists in the e.parameter (inside doPost function)?

Comment: Yes, using readonly="readonly" instead of disabled. It Worked. Thansk.